# Why std::ostreambuf_iterator truncates integers?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm copying a sorted vector of uint32_t numbers into a binary stream via `std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>{stream})`, but it truncates numbers, turns them into 1-byte numbers.

What's wrong with my code? I have got a workaround, but maybe it's possible to make the ostreambuf_iterator approach work properly?

```cpp
std::ofstream chunk{ "filename.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out };

// this piece of code works not expected
std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>{chunk});

// But this, alternative works good
for (auto& v : numbers)
    chunk.write((char*)& v, sizeof uint32_t);
```

I expected to have this output:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000
0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000
```

But my output is:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 0101
0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm copying a sorted vector of uint32_t numbers into a binary stream via `std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>{stream})`, but it truncates numbers, turns them into 1-byte numbers.

Yep — you asked it to!

You have a range of `uint32_t`, then you're using a `char` iterator.

So each element is converted to a `char` as it goes through.

`std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>` doesn't automatically alias input elements with a different type. This would be illegal in most cases, plus it would have to do buffering to provide (in this example) four outputs for each one input: now imagine you provided `char`s to a `ostreambuf_iterator<uint32_t>`, and realise that it would have to provide one output for each four inputs, which gets more complicated. This is just not what this iterator is for.

You will want to treat the range as a range of `char` instead; fortunately, this is legal due to an aliasing exemption. We can't use vector iterators any more, but that's fine because we can get direct access to its contiguous data in the form of pointers, and do what we like with those pointers:

```
std::copy(
   reinterpret_cast<const char*>(numbers.data()),
   reinterpret_cast<const char*>(numbers.data() + numbers.size()),
   std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>{stream}
);
```

This is practically equivalent to your second example.

Comment: I think your example will omit the final element?

Comment: @Lightness Races with Monica, thank you for the explanation! (I'd wish STL had some compile-time checks in this iterator, tho)

Comment: @user24601 There is no check, because your code is valid, is just means something else. It converts the `uint32_t` value to a `char` value and then prints the character. That would make sense if your `uint32_t` contained values representing individual characters. `std::ostreambuf_iterator` is formatted output anyway.

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Good spot!